# Verifying If statement with correct condition

Tags: c#

```cs
DataRow currentStatusRow = DB.RtnRow(
@"SELECT TOP 1 ob.Status, obd.descr, obd.OutboxDetailID FROM OutboxDetail obd 
JOIN outbox ob ON obd.OutboxId = ob.OutboxID 
WHERE ob.OutboxID = @0 ORDER BY OutboxDetailID DESc", 0, outbox.outboxID);

if (currentStatusRow["Descr"].ToString() != "Attempting Resend" 
  && (currentStatusRow["Status"].ToInt() != outbox.status.ToInt() || 
      currentStatusRow["OutboxDetailID"].ToInt() > 0))
return;
```

So I have a question regarding the `if` statement above. I'm trying to make sure that the condition doesn't return out/exit as long as the `"Descr"` has a value of `"Attempting Resend"`.  If the `"Descr"` column has that specific description, I want to continue with the code below.

My breakpoints are somehow unbound when testing this so, finding it hard to test. Does the condition look correct?

Comment: If `currentStatusRow["Descr"].ToString() != "Attempting Resend"` evaluates to false, it doesn't check the rest of the condition. If true, it will check the rest of your conditions.

Comment: Right, that condition will evaluate to false _only if_ `"Attempting Resend"` is the value of the `"Descr"` column, right?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "that condition"? The condition of the `if` statement will also evaluate to `false` if `(currentStatusRow["Status"].ToInt() != outbox.status.ToInt() || 
currentStatusRow["OutboxDetailID"].ToInt() > 0)` evaluates to false. If you don't want that part of the condition, remove it...

Comment: I need that part of the condition. All I want is for the condition to not exit out if `"Attempting Resend"` is the value for `"Descr"`. If it is, then just continue the code and ignore the rest of the condition. Otherwise, look into the rest of the condition (status and outboxdetailID).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should write the code to clearly express its intent, even if this sometimes results in an extra line or two. Unclear code is like a dark corner in a basement- hard to see where the bugs could be.

Some people may be able to parse the conditional given in the question easily (I am not one of them); however, given that you are asking about its behavior, you should consider that it's not clear enough.

You mention in the question that if the "Descr" column has the specific value of "Attempting Resend", then you want to make sure the method doesn't return. Consider writing the code below, which I think clearly shows what the expected path is:

```
// Don't allow possibility of returning if the status description is "Attempting Resend":
if (currentStatusRow["Descr"].ToString() != "Attempting Resend")
{
    if (currentStatusRow["Status"].ToInt() != outbox.status.ToInt() || 
        currentStatusRow["OutboxDetailID"].ToInt() > 0)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is cleaner. Thank you

Comment: It may be that, in the larger context of this method, these conditions could be made even better, but I won't speculate on this with the lines as given.